# Update list element in python

Tags: python, json, list

In my python code If I have a list like this:

```
   my_list= [{"name": "my name", "timestamp": {"$date": 1459002562091}, "longitude": 20.169550966746304, "location": "Work", "victim": {"language": "English", "locality": "Bern", "gender": "Other", "region": "Gabon", "birthday": {"$date": 506736000000}, "nationality": "United States", "ethnicity": "Bosnian"}, "person": "Stranger", "latitude": 43.05529651674635, "personGender": "Male", "type": ["Shouting"]}, {"name": "my name", "timestamp": {"$date": 1455632962091}, "longitude": 21.292620354706038, "location": "Public Space", "victim": {"language": "English", "locality": "Ferizaj", "gender": "Other", "region": "Kosovo", "birthday": {"$date": 601516800000}, "nationality": "Canada", "ethnicity": "Turkish"}, "person": "Waiter", "latitude": 42.81558228232729, "personGender": "Male", "type": ["Comments", "Whistling"]}]
```

I want to modify this list to make a check inside JSON elements of this list, then I want to find element `name` to check their value and I use another function to replace the value, so here I will use as an example "Just an example string".

And also for type, if the type is I make the same check and replace their value with another function but here I will put the same value "Type example".

So I started like this:

```
for item in my_list:
    item["name"] = "Just an example string"
    for element in item["type"]:
        element = "Type example"
```

Now I want to save those updated fields in the same list, so I just update these two fields and others should remain the same? How can I do that? Please help me

Comment: Thats actually a Python dictionary, not JSON

Comment: You have a Python list, and a malformed one at that. You may have loaded the data from JSON, but that doesn't matter to how you then use the structure.

Comment: @cricket_007 I just tried to delete te actual values and put example values, for that I made mistakes in the python dictionary.

Comment: It looks like you should have used [`loads`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html#bson.json_util.loads) from [`bson.json_util`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html). This is data returned in [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) format afterall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use indexing instead of `for something in iterable:` notation:

```
for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
    my_list[i]["name"] = "Just an example string"
    for j in range(0, len(my_list[i]["type"])):
        my_list[i]["type"][j] = "Type example"
```

This will update your *list of dictionaries* (not JSON) in place.

**Edit**: as pointed out by @gtlambert, it's not necessary to put a zero as the first argument to `range`, you can write just `range(some_number)`.

Comment: You don't need to use `0` as an argument to `range`

Comment: @cricket_007, I was supposing this is simply a _big_ typo. Perhaps the OP was typing that all over again instead of copying & pasting.

Comment: You do not need to use a range to modify the inside of a list or a dictionary in python. Iteration of dictionaries and lists in python is by reference. Any change to the referenced item will be reflected in the original dictionary/list.

Comment: @ForceBru thanks a lot for ur answer! I'm getting this error: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str at my_list[i]["name"]

Comment: @EgzEst, please copy & paste the list in your answer (I've edited it) and run this again

Comment: @MichaelRobellard, at least in Python 2.7.10, this seems to be incorrect: `l = [1,2,3,4,5]; for x in l: x = 0; print l` prints `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: In your example you are using integers, try this: 
l = [{'a':1},{'a': 2},{'a': 3},{'a': 4},{'a': 5}]; for x in l: x['a'] = 0; print l

Comment: @ForceBru I updated my list , now I put there the real one, can you check it please

Comment: @MichaelRobellard I don't get ur answer, can u explain to me please

Comment: @EgzEst, yep, it's correct. You can check it yourself: paste it into your Python interpreter and it'll check whether there are any errors or not

Comment: @ForceBru  I have this error : TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str at my_list[i]["name"]

Comment: @EgzEst, you _cannot_ encounter this error. Double-check your list and the code. I've just it and everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

In Python lists and dictionaries are mutable and passed by reference and strings, numbers and tuples are immutable, and passed by value.

Therefore if you iterate over a list of ints or strings using for x in l: you will not be able to change them because x is the actual value of the int or string.

```
In [17]: l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [18]: for x in l:
   ....:     x = 0
   ....:     

In [19]: l
Out[19]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

However when you have a list of dictionaries everything changes:

```
In [31]: l=[{'a':1}, {'a':2}]

In [32]: for x in l:
   ....:     x['a'] = 0
   ....:     

In [33]: l
Out[33]: [{'a': 0}, {'a': 0}]
```

Your original example therefore works as you wrote where you can change the dictionary items inside the list, but you cannot change the type in the same way because it is simply a list of strings.

```
In [14]: my_list = [
   ....:     {"id": 1 ,"number":12, "name": "test1", "type":["read"]}, 
   ....:     {"id": 1 ,"number":12, "name": "test2","type":["write"]},
   ....:     {"id": 1 ,"number":12, "name": "test3","type":["read", "write"]}
   ....:     ]

In [15]: for item in my_list:
   ....:         item["name"] = "Just an example string"
   ....:         for element in item["type"]:
   ....:                 element = "Type example"
   ....:         

In [16]: my_list
Out[16]: 
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Just an example string', 'number': 12, 'type': ['read']},
 {'id': 1, 'name': 'Just an example string', 'number': 12, 'type': ['write']},
 {'id': 1,
  'name': 'Just an example string',
  'number': 12,
  'type': ['read', 'write']}]

In [17]:
```

Here is a more pythonic solution to the problem:

```
In [35]: for item in my_list:
   ....:     item["name"] = "Just an example string"
   ....:     item["type"] = ["Type Example" for element in item["type"]]
   ....:     

In [36]: my_list
Out[36]: 
[{'id': 1,
  'name': 'Just an example string',
  'number': 12,
  'type': ['Type Example']},
 {'id': 1,
  'name': 'Just an example string',
  'number': 12,
  'type': ['Type Example']},
 {'id': 1,
  'name': 'Just an example string',
  'number': 12,
  'type': ['Type Example', 'Type Example']}]

In [37]:
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how you can update list items in python

```
list = ['physics', 'chemistry', 1997, 2000];
print "Value available at index 2 : "
print list[2]
list[2] = 2001;
print "New value available at index 2 : "
print list[2]
```